# Berkshelf Gemfile version conflict

Tags: chef, rubygems, berkshelf

I received the following error from the berks command when trying to init a new cookbook to use Berkshelf version 3

```
Could not find proper version of berkshelf (2.0.17) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I do not want to run "bundle install" as it recommends since the whole point was to use Berkshelf v3. How can I get this cookbook to accept Berkshelf v3?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to do the following to fix the issue; adjust the Gemfile to use berkshelf v3 e.g.,

```
gem 'berkshelf', '~> 3'
```

then, remove the old Gemfile.lock and run

```
bundle install
berks init
```

taking care not to overwrite any site specific files (such as kitchen tests).

Comment: If the Gemfile didn't have the version constraint before, this may have come as a constraint from a Gemfile.lock, which may be pulled in from a previous run of `bundler`, or checked into SCM by someone else.